# os.path.dirname(__file__) returns empty

Tags: python

I want to get the path of the current directory under which a .py file is executed.

For example a simple file `D:\test.py` with code:

```
import os

print os.getcwd()
print os.path.basename(__file__)
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

It is weird that the output is:

```
D:\
test.py
D:\test.py
EMPTY
```

I am expecting the same results from the `getcwd()` and `path.dirname()`.

Given `os.path.abspath = os.path.dirname + os.path.basename`, why

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

returns empty?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Because `os.path.abspath = os.path.dirname + os.path.basename` does not hold.  we rather have

```
os.path.dirname(filename) + os.path.basename(filename) == filename
```

Both `dirname()` and `basename()` only split the passed filename into components without taking into account the current directory.  If you want to also consider the current directory, you have to do so explicitly.

To get the dirname of the absolute path, use

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: note the above comment has a bold where there should be underline on both sides because of markdown formatting. the original answer was changed correctly

Comment: Note that we never have `os.path.dirname(filename) + os.path.basename(filename) == filename` because the directory separator is missing.
We rather have:
`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), os.path.basename(filename)) == filename`

Comment: I am confused, should you leave basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
in your program ? or what do you replace or where to you replace your path like C:\Users\Test\app.db?

Comment: @pes04 `__file__` expands to the name of the current file, so you can use a verbatim copy of the code from this answer.

Comment: Why I got error ```NameError: name '__file__' is not defined```

Comment: @Cecilia I can only guess, but probalby because you are trying this in an interactive interpreter, where `__file__` doesn't make sense?

Comment: Hi @SvenMarnach Yeah I'm using Jupyter Notebook, but ```os.path()``` returns the dir.

Answer (score 13):

```
import os.path

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
```

Comment: Awesome answer!  Not quite what the OP was asking for, but EXACTLY what I was looking for

Comment: For some strange reason my __file__ seems to be empty on some machines and non-empty on others, but this answer fixed my thing for good.

Answer (score 10):

```
os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]
```

`os.path.realpath(__file__)`return the abspath of the current script;     os.path.split(abspath)[0] return the current dir

Answer (score 9):

can be used also like that:

```
dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

You can also use this way

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3.4, you can use `pathlib` to get the file's directory:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# get parent directory
curr_dir = Path(__file__).parent

file_path = curr_dir.joinpath('otherfile.txt')
```

Edit: To get the current directory use

```py
Path.cwd()
```

Thanks `@Nuno André`

Comment: `Path(__file__).parent` returns the _file's directory_. To get the _current directory_ (i.e. the directory of the process, not the file) you can use `Path.cwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers is correct. OP wants *to get the path of the **current directory** under which a .py file is **executed**,* not stored.

Thus, if the path of this file is `/opt/script.py`...

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

# -- file's directory -- where the file is stored
fd = Path(__file__).parent

# -- current directory -- where the file is executed
# (i.e. the directory of the process)
cwd = Path.cwd()

print(f'{fd=} {cwd=}')
```

Only if we run this script from `/opt`, `fd` and `cwd` will be the same.

```bash
$ cd /
$ /opt/script.py
cwd=PosixPath('/') fd=PosixPath('/opt')

$ cd opt
$ ./script.py
cwd=PosixPath('/opt') fd=PosixPath('/opt')

$ cd child
$ ../script.py
cwd=PosixPath('/opt/child') fd=PosixPath('/opt/child/..')
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is a straight forward code without the os module..

```
__file__.split(__file__.split("/")[-1])[0]
```