# python 2.7 os.path.dirname(__file__) returns empty string on Debian (works fine on Win7)

Tags: python, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [os.path.dirname(__file__) returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783308/os-path-dirname-file-returns-empty)

Here's my piece of code:

```
def GetAppPath():
    application_path = None
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    elif __file__:
        application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return application_path
```

Works perfectly on Windows, but returns empty string on Debian. Any ideas what could be the problem?

I'm using Python 2.7.3, Debian 6.0.5

Comment: Have you thought about adding print statements to inspect which branch of the conditional clause you enter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783308/os-path-dirname-file-returns-empty

Comment: Are you running this in the root directory?

Comment: @mgilson: I've inspected the branches: the second one is executed

Comment: @Artur Gadelshin: thank you that's what I was looking for. Too bad I didn't notice it myself

Answer (score 1):

Seems like __file__ is not defined or defined incorrectly, works for me on Debian testing, Python 2.7.3rc2

```
    def GetAppPath(file):
        application_path = os.path.dirname(file)
        return application_path
```

GetAppPath('/etc/X11/xorg.conf') returns '/etc/X11'

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on Ubuntu 12.04/python 2.7:

```
import os.path

print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Store in /tmp/foo.py and then run it:

```
$ python /tmp/foo.py 
/tmp
```