# (os.path.dirname(__file__)) not working in FreeBSD

Tags: python, django, freebsd

I want to set the path to the images dir..in my Django project...it is working fine but when i run the script on FreeBSD it is not working...

```
import os 

imagesDirPath = (os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/couponRestApiApp/stores/images/"
print imagesDirPath

output: /home/vaibhav/TRAC/coupon-rest-api/couponRestApi/couponRestApiApp/stores/images/
```

Above is working on my system but when tried it on freeBSD i get:

```
/couponRestApiApp/stores/images/
```

but it should be

```
/home/vaibhav/coupon-rest-api/couponRestApi/couponRestApiApp/stores/images/
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong...

Comment: Did you try `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7783326/722332

Comment: This is *not* a FreeBSD problem but a problem how you invoke the script. `__file__` is not guaranteed to be an absolute path.