# Django's Syncdb and russian symbols in path

Tags: python, django

I created a Django project and Django app. I want Django to create SQLite database for my project. I run `manage.py syncdb` but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\home\Google ─шёъ\Python\testsite\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 160, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 347, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

What's wrong?

Here is database settings from `settings.py`:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your database settings.

Comment: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: @user23791 yes, but what is the actual path to settings?

Answer (score 1):

The first (a bit general) advice that I can give you is to start **all** your Python files with this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

You'll spare yourself a lot of trouble when dealing with foreign symbols.

Now, if that didn't help, perhaps check if you have write access to the directory where you try to create the database file (`BASE_DIR`).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common when you're using sqlite3 as a database: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3

Make sure that both the file `db.sqlite3` and the directory that contains it (in this case your `BASE_DIR`) have the correct permission settings. 
Usually (depending on the OS)

```
chown -R www-data:www-data path_to_basedir
```

does the trick

Answer (score 1):

The `os.path.dirname(path)` returns the directory of a pathname. This assumes that the path is passed as an input, and not a file as you are currently doing.
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

> `os.path.dirname(path)`
>
> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

You are using `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`, which will return an empty string, and hence your `NAME` value will not be correct.

Check the following demo on the python prompt (Taking hints from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7783308/1860929)):

```
>>> import os
>>> __file__ = "test.py" #Don't use this line if running from within a file
>>> print os.path.dirname(__file__)

>>> print os.path.abspath(__file__)
/home/user/Desktop/test/test.py
>>> print os.path.basename(__file__)
test.py
>>> print os.getcwd()
/home/user/Desktop/test
>>> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
>>> NAME =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
>>> print BASE_DIR, len(BASE_DIR)
 0
>>> print NAME, len(NAME)
db.sqlite3 10
```

So, you need to redefine the value of your `BASE_NAME`, and can use the below in your settings file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.getcwd()
# Or alternatively, use below commented line
# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

** Make sure there is no special charcaters in the path like "éè" or "(". **

[Django says "Unable to Open Database File" when using SQLite3](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3)