# os.path.dirname returning empty string in django

Tags: python, django, path

I am new to the python django framework and I could not quite understand why

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

and

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

return an empty string.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
djangoWorkspace/
  tangoWithDjangoProject/
     rango/
     tangoWithDjangoProject/
          settings.py
```

Settings.py contains the code for the dirname.

Comment: possible duplicate of [os.path.dirname(\_\_file\_\_) returns empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783308/os-path-dirname-file-returns-empty)

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: what is the Python and Django Version?

Comment: python is 2.7.6 and django is 1.7

Comment: What is the output of `print __file__` in settings.py?

Comment: @TarangHirani actually it answers the question. However, it seems you would like to know why `__file__` returns only filename in your case.

Comment: No, I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html) which has that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` does not make any sense. You need to call `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` as suggested in the duplicate question.

The result is empty because `__file__` contains only the file name of the Python file.

`os.path.dirname` does not resolve the location of the given file but simply strips away the file name from the given string.

```
os.path.dirname('../foo/bar/baz.txt')
Out[4]: '../foo/bar'
```

As you can see the path has not been resolved, the `bar.txt` has simply been removed from the string.

What you're doing is the equivalent of:

```
__file__ = 'baz.txt'

os.path.dirname(__file__)
Out[6]: ''
```

Instead you should do:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Out[10]: '/home/noxdafox/foo/bar'
```

Comment: I was following the tutorial [here](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html) which has the code I wrote above. And the django library auto generated that code.

Comment: For some reason, using os.path.abspath doesn't work but os.path.dirname works. Not sure why. Can you provide an explanation for that?

Comment: To be clear: all the mentioned methods are not performing a lookup in the FS to find the correct place of the given string. The [os.path.abspath documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) clearly shows how the function tries to resolve the given path. It's an educated guess and not a reliable search. To better understand what's going on I'd rather print the \__file__ content and the value returned by `os.getcwd`.