# Python: Having difficulty obtaining current path of script

Tags: python, macos, path, pycharm, sys

I'm very new to programming, and to Python. I'm on Mac OSX, trying to work with PyCharm. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/python-path-of-script), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory-with-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-to-get-full-path-of-current-files-directory-in-python), and *several* more.

But I can't seem to get the path of the current running file. If I use `os.getcwd()`, I get

```
'/Users/AlanH/Python'
```

When really, the full file path is:

```
'/Users/AlanH/Python/Exercises/PythonBasics/starthere.py'
```

So I don't understand why that doesn't work.

If I try using `sys.path[0]`, it prings up a path that takes me to my Library, then dives in to Enthought (don't know why, even though I'm using Anaconda distribution).

I could go on and on about all the possible solutions I've tried, but nothing works. All I want is to get the exact path up to current running file. So either

```
'/Users/AlanH/Python/Exercises/PythonBasics/starthere.py'
```

or this

```
'/Users/AlanH/Python/Exercises/PythonBasics'
```

will do.

Could someone please help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/51523/3166303

Comment: What do you get when you use `__file__` ?

Comment: @leeor If I use that solution, it doesn't give the proper path. It gives `'/Users/AlanH/Python/starthere.py'`, which I don't understand because no such file exists in my Python folder

Comment: @AnandSKumar I don't understand how to use that. Do I literally type in `__file__`?

Comment: @AlanH do `print(__file__)` for now to test.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I literally typed in `print(__file__)` and I got back `name  '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: do that in the script, not directly in a python terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Locally tested with the following result:

```
eb@cube ~/Share $ python stackoverflow/path.py
/home/eb/Share/stackoverflow/path.py
```

Comment: @ErikBirkeland Do you literally, verbatim, type `__file__` ? Or is that a representation for your file name?

Comment: Yes. `__file__` is a variable of sorts containing the file name, or so it should.

Comment: Have a look here perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783308/os-path-dirname-file-returns-empty

Comment: I've tested the above on Python 2.7.4 and 3.4.0 on Linux, as well as 2.7.3 on Windows 7. Hm.

Comment: Can you try this:
`print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`