# PyQt QWebkitWidgets not displaying web page when called from command line or object constructor

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qwebkit

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
import sys
import os

class Navigation(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.
             JavascriptEnabled,True)
        #self.web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.
        #    JavascriptCanOpenWindows, True)
        self.web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.
            JSAC, True)

        #self.web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.
        #DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
        filepath = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MapSite.html')
        self.web.show()
        self.web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex= Navigation()
app.exec_()
```

This PyQt program display a webpage only when run from IDLE for python3. When I run this program fom command line or make a Navigation class object by importing in other files, the webpage not displayed, just white screen

***EDIT***

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/RaspiCallSystem4 $ python3 navigation.py 
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: no
```

when I execute from command line It give above output, web window starts but with white page only, running from IDLE executes smoothly

[image]

Comment: How do you execute the file in the command line? Is the cmd or terminal open in the path where the .py and .html file are located?

Comment: sorry I run on terminal using "python3 navigation.py" and yes terminal opened in that path

Comment: In the RaspiCallSystem4 folder are the .py and the .html? On the other hand, have you been able to run QtWebKit on raspberry pi? that I know did not have support for it.

Comment: please show how you execute the command and all the messages that the console sends you, it is important to understand where the problem is

Comment: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: no

executing from command line give this output but web window still run with no white screen

Comment: try changing `filepath` with fullpath. By other hand execute `print(filepath)`

Comment: yes, it's running on giving full path, but that's not friendly if path changed. So, whats the problem here @eyllanesc

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 0):

As the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7783326/6622587) indicates in some cases the command `os.path.dirname(__file__)` can return an empty string, and that's the case of the terminal, so there are 2 possible solutions:

```
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'MapSite.html')
```

Or:

```
filepath = QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('MapSite.html')
```